# How to add 5 button on NavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to add on around 5 buttons on UINavigation bar .

I fine we can add button to left and right for the navigation

using UIToolbar we add the button on navigation bar.

Is any other way which fit around five button's around navigation bar.  where apple is accepted

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview: abutton];`.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];

// create a standard "1" button
UIBarButtonItem* bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:NULL];
bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

//for spacer
bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

// create a standard "2" button
bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refresh:)];
bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

// and so on you can create rest button in the same way and add to tools
// stick the buttons in the toolbar
[tools setItems:buttons animated:NO];
[buttons release];
 // and put the toolbar in the nav bar
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]   initWithCustomView:tools];
[tools release];
```